# TinyMCE is removing some part of html

Tags: javascript, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I want to be able to insert empty div and span elements, text like [something], but when I save TinyMCE is removing all this code.

Is there a config option that tells TinyMCE to return me the exact text I've entered?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to change your valid_elements config option to somethin like

```
    // The valid_elements option defines which elements will remain in the edited text when the editor saves.
    valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style|onmouseover]," +
    "a[name|href|target|title|alt]," +
    "p,blockquote,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src|height|width],-sub,-sup,-b,-i,-u," +
    "span[data-mce-type],hr",
```

Iportant here is that the 'P' and 'span' elements does not have a minus standing right before.