# TinyMCE 4 removing portion of my text

Tags: php, html, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I'm using TinyMCE 4.0.12 as my RichText editor.  I'm using textarea mode.

When the text area contains some poorly thought out escape strings that I had no part in designing, i.e. <-custName->, TinyMCE doesn't render them in the body of the editor.  Is there a setting that I'm missing that will prevent it from stripping these out, as I assume it's considering them invalid HTML tags and removing them.

Any help is greatly appreciated, because otherwise I have to wade through a sea of spaghetti code and completely rework the way this system escapes special values.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000237/tinymce-is-removing-some-part-of-html?rq=1

Comment: bottom line here is that yes, those placeholders are poorly thought out. TinyMCE will see them as invalid HTML and remove them as part of its HTML cleansing process. Not much you can do about it. And no, don't go digging into TinyMCE's code to try to "fix" it; it's not going to be something you can just fix. Best advice I can give: use a pre-processing script to convert those badly designed placeholder codes into something a bit more sensible before giving the code to TinyMCE.

Comment: When I said spaghetti code, I was referring to the code base I inherited, not TinyMCE.  I actually ended up solving it by doing a str_replace() on the the way in and out to {{custName}}, which not only looks nicer, but doesn't break TinyMCE.